# The answer is buried there somewhere

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

Wow, the little negative cow army had a balmy sun war.
The forty richest blameless homesteaders await the answers.

*Who did the cow army fight in the war?*

Hint #1:

> arMy

Hint #2:

> I wouldn't mess with 2,3,7, or 8.  They seem pretty tough.

Hint #3:

> You may get some help from *Sherry, my nurse*.

Comment: It feels like there's at least one tag missing here ...

Comment: Added a couple of tags.

Comment: @Rubio $\diamondsuit$ when I first looked at the puzzle, I totally agreed; but believing that adding such tags would give away clues, I left the riddle alone... I couldn't solve it xD

Comment: That was my initial concern - I planned on adding tags as "clues" as needed.  The tags I added are probably enough, I think.  Additional hint added as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The whole mysterious text

> is an anagram of
>  MARY HAD A LITTLE LAMB
>  ITS FLEECE WAS WHITE AS SNOW
>  AND EVERYWHERE THAT MARY WENT
>  THE LAMB WAS SURE TO GO
>  OSTRICHES

so I'm guessing the cows were fighting the

> ostriches.

(All credit to @Alconja for doing the hard work. If you like this answer, go and upvote Alconja's. Opinions eagerly solicited on whether I should delete this so that Alconja can get *all* the credit.)

Incidentally, the hints

> led me completely up the wrong garden path, because the numbers 2,3,7,8 happen to have something in common -- they are exactly the digits that can't come at the end of a square number -- and then "Sherry my nurse" has word-lengths 6,2,5 and 625 is 5 squared squared ... so I was sure there were some mathematical shenanigans afoot :-).

Comment: Ha!  I usually stick to word-play in my riddles, but enjoy solving the math ones so maybe you've inspired my next riddle here :)

Comment: Yes, ostriches is correct.  Nice work to both.  I appreciate asking about credit,but since he explicitly stated his answer could be a starting point for someone else, I'll give you the check.

Comment: This is an outrage! I *demand* that you delete this immediately *and* step down as moderator! (warning: comment may contain traces of sarcasm)

Answer (score 12):

**Partial, possible solution...** (or at least theory...)

From hint #1:

> *arMy* is an anagram of **Mary**

From hint #2:

> *the* (word number 2), *little* (3), *had* (7), and *a* (8) are going to be difficult to anagram, so not all words are...

From hint #3:

> *Sherry, my nurse* => *Nurse Sherry* => **Nursery (rhyme)**

Given these, it seems we're dealing with:

> A jumbled, cryptically described, homophoned, and partially anagrammed nursery rhyme, possibly **Mary Had a Little Lamb**(?).

In detail, we have:

*Wow, the little negative cow army had a balmy sun war.*

> *army had a* => **Mary had a**
>  *little* => **little**
>  *balmy* => **lamb(y)**
>  ...whose?
>  *sun war* => *run was* => *flee was* => **fleece was**
>  ...white as snow?
>  (unused bits: *Wow, the negative cow*)

Not really sure where to go from there. I'm obviously still missing something, but thought this might at least be a starting place for someone else...

Comment: Very much on the right track.  Basically, just continue on and you're sure to get there

Comment: Also, you got hint 3 in an interesting different way than intended, but same result!

Comment: Overall, it's not too jumbled, cryptic, homophoned or partial.  Hopefully that will help.

Comment: @MetaZen perhaps your intended solution to hint 3 is rot13( [fureel zl ahefr]-> nantenz:[ahefrel eulzr])?

Comment: That's correct.  But @alconja also got there a different way haha

Comment: Is this the cow that jumped over the moon?

Comment: Ha. The hints had me on _completely_ the wrong track. Allow me to remark that rot13(N ONYZL FHA JNE vf na nantenz bs EHANJNL YNZOF.)