# What solves the riddle and the situation?

Tags: word, wordplay, knowledge

Those totally brainwashed millionaire wolf degenerates devastated PhD academic honor.
Kids defend.
Devastation.

Hint #1:

> Perhaps you could get some help from *Professor Bermott*?

Hint #2

> Or by looking closely at some *Aegean hedge scans*?

Comment: Nice puzzle, MetaZen! I assume that this is in the theme of your previous puzzles? Regardless, "totally brainwashed millionaire wolf degenerates" is my favorite new insult.

Comment: If that’s your favorite new insult, wait until you see the answer!

Comment: Oh, dear. This can't end well.

Comment: If this puzzle follows the same mechanism as your previous ones (and I'm certain that it does), then I feel it's a bit underclued, since the question is broader this time around. Without a computer to brute force or additional hints, I'm not sure how one would go about solving this despite knowing the mechanism involved.

Comment: @PiIsNot3 - I agree.  Hint #1 added

Comment: Hint #2 as well.  Couldn't help myself.

Comment: Also want to say, this puzzle sort of wrote itself.  It will appear to be much more planned out than it was when the answer has been found!

Comment: added knowledge tag, though the main phrase to solve it is pretty well known, I think

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like the [previous](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/81518/the-answer-is-buried-there-somewhere) [puzzles](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/82040/who-got-some-sun-on-the-voyage) posted by OP, the trick here is that

> the text can be anagrammed to form both a well-known quote and a leftover phrase that answers the question posed in the title.

From Hint 1,

> we know that we are looking for ROBERT FROST POEMS, which is an anagram of the italicized phrase.

I believe then that what we're looking at is

> an anagrammed version of the last three lines of the last stanza of Frost's well-known poem [Road Not Taken](https://www.poets.org/poetsorg/poem/road-not-taken) (the remaining letters are tacked on at the end):
>
>  TWO ROADS DIVERGED IN A WOOD, AND I
>  I TOOK THE ONE LESS TRAVELED BY
>  AND THAT HAS MADE ALL THE DIFFERENCE
>  AACDEIILMNPSST
>
>  (Hint 2 actually leads us to this conclusion, since the italicized phrase anagrams to AGES AND AGES HENCE, which appears in the line directly before these three.)

The remaining letters

> anagrams to **CAPITALISM ENDS**, which I guess *could* resolve the situation between the kids and the millionaires, but that's a rabbit hole I'm not willing to go down.

---

*Side note:*

> The OP also stated in the comments that the poem tangentially relates to the final answer. I interpreted that as referring to how [Frost wrote about issues regarding the rise of industrialism](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3195410), but it turns out it was even more of a stretch than that - the remaining letters can also anagram to SEND CAPITALISM (one of my initial guesses), which makes two "diverging roads" with regards to how to solve the issue presented in the problem.

Comment: Excellent work, but the final answer is something different and possibly related to the title, the puzzle, and the poem if you stretch it a bit.

Comment: Hmm, I'm looking through the list and can't seem to find any other good fits besides rot13(FRAQ PNCVGNYVFZ). Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Very very close, but also quite the opposite.  Although, depending on someone's political leanings, your answer could fit too, I suppose.

Comment: Based on @MetaZen's comments, presumably that makes it "ends"... not "send"..., which was one of the ones I had in my list, which kind of tenuously works with the riddle. (though a riddle about a wolf and baby goats also "depicts animals").

Comment: I had it flipped around, but close enough for the check mark.  Like I said in the above comment, I didn’t set out for that kind of answer, but my method of creating these just sort of spit it out when I was working through the poem.  Fun one!  And I’ll take your point about the solvability without hints for future ones.

Comment: @Brandon_J your fears have been confirmed (well, it depends on your perspective)

Comment: And with regard to the poem. I suppose “send capitalism” and “capitalism ends” are something like a fork in the road.  A stretch, but that was all I meant.